# Could not find method share(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute

Tags: android, share

I'm trying to implement a basic share button that takes a screenshot of the activity and then allows you to share that image.

however, when I click the button to call the method, I get the error in my Title.

```
    public static void share(Context context, View view, boolean incText, 
    String text){
    try{

        File mPath = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "screenshot.png");
        //File imageDirectory = new File(mPath, "screenshot.png");

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(mPath);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(mPath);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        if(incText){
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        }
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
    }catch (Throwable tr){

    }
```

This is the error I recieve

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.companieshousegraphexplorer02, PID: 28900
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method share(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28900 SIG: 9
    Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have `android:onClick="share"` in your layout for this button.

That means that the method signature for `share()` needs to be:

```
public void share(View view)
```

and that `share()` method needs to be implemented on your activity.

Also:

- `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ — use `FileProvider`
- There is no guarantee that your "drawing cache" approach will work — consider using [a screenshot library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/237)

Comment: but if i change the method signature to `public void share(View view)` how do I then deal with the other variables that are not being passed.

Comment: @Beeblebug: You do not need `Context` -- you can get that by calling `getContext()` on the `View`. In terms of the other two, I do not know where you were planning on getting those values from. You may be better served removing `android:onClick` from the layout and using `setOnClickListener()` in your Java code.